# Action overflow menus for elements of a list view

Tags: android, view, menu

The overflow actions menu looks exactly like what I need, but it seems to only work within action bars. However, I'd like this kind of three-dots-menu on the right side of each element of a list view.

[image: Action overflow menu outside of action bar]

Is there a built-in view that can be used for this?

Comment: you can check this http://keepsafe.github.io/2014/11/19/building-a-custom-overflow-menu.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an `ImageView` and a `PopupMenu`.

```
Context context = ...
ImageView overflow = ...

PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, overflow);
popup.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_resource);
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(...);

overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public final void onClick(View v) {
            popup.show();
        }
}
overflow.setOnTouchListener(popup.getDragToOpenListener());
```

Comment: Where does one find the "three dot" icon resource to use for the overflow button?